# How to read a file line by line in PHP if lines are separated with 0x0A?

Tags: php, parsing, fgets

We have a 8 GB file, each line is a `serialize()` output, so it can contain binary data. But I've noticed that data doesn't contain the `0x0A` byte and that byte is used to separate lines in a file.

The function `fgets()` doesn't help, because it detects end-of-line on both `0x0A` or `0x0D` bytes, so `fgets()` sees more line separators than exists.

Is there a `fgets()` version that uses only the `0x0A` byte as a line separator for my case?

Is there another approach without coding my own reading-buffering-parsing-lines-emitting solution?

*P.S.* `file_get_contents()` doesnt like files larger than 2GB.

Comment: `$temp = file_get_contents('foo.txt'); $lines = preg_split('/[\x0a\x0d]+/', $temp);`?

Comment: You can use fgets(), test for the last character, and stitch lines together if it's a 0x0D

Comment: usually, php detects \n or \r\n as line endings. simple carriage returns are detected as line endings only if auto_detect_line_endings is set to true (false is default). What's your auto_detect_line_endings setting saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably try:

```
string stream_get_line ( resource $handle , int $length [, string $ending ] );
//i.e.
string stream_get_line ($handle , filesize($myFile) , '\n' );
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

My current solution is based on comment of user Jonid Bendo:
`stream_get_line()` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php ), but on my platform, `stream_get_line()` doesn't return lines longer than 8192 bytes, so I use a loop around it to detect that and reconstruct longer strings:

```
$master = "";
do
{
    $line = stream_get_line ($handle, 1024*128, "\n");
    $ll = strlen($line);
    if ($ll < 1) {
        break;
    }

    $badline = ($ll == 8192) && ('\n' != $line[$ll-1]);

    $master .= $line;

} while( $badline );
```